# use space for thousands separator reporting services

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need shows the number with space for thousands Ex: 650 128,33 or 1 150,39

How can I do this in reporting services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `Format` property for your textbox, you can simply enter the format with the space:

`# ###,##`

Comment: This not work, because do in this format 6 70.351 instead of 670 351

Answer (score 2):

You could use expression for the value:

```
=replace(Format(650 128,33, "## ### ##0.##") ,".",",")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have negative number you will have minus so far away from number.

I use this formula:

```
=switch(len(format(abs(me.value),"0"))<7,"## ##0",len(format(abs(me.value),"0"))<13 and len(format(abs(me.value),"0"))>=7,"## ### ### ##0")
```